# How can I do a copy of my spreadsheet into specifc folder in google drive using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script that when end of run, I want to make a copy of that spreadsheet into a specific folder with name + date, for example:

I have the spreadsheet called "Audit", When some specific script run at the end I want to make a copy for the spreadsheet into the folder root/Audit/Historic into google driver or google docs.

Note: root is the google driver or google docs top folder.

Script:

```
  function ShellCopyValues(){
        var sheets = ['sheet1','sheet2','sheet3','sheet4','sheet4'];
        for (var s in sheets){
        CopyRows(sheets[s]);
      }
  }

  function CopyRows(uname) {
   var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXX');
   var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName(uname);

   var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YYYYYY');
   var targetsheet = target.getSheetByName(uname);
   var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
   var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
   targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);

   }
```

At the end of this script I want to make a copy.

I will appreciate if anyone have any idea about how can I do it.

## EDIT: 08/07/2013 (Fixed)

- The script will make a copy with this format (filename+date)
- The script will save the file into a folder. (Will not appear in the root "My Driver")

  ```
  //This part make a copy of the spreadsheet
  var SSID = 'XXXXXX'
  var CopyDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "ddMMyyyyHHmm"); // Function Date + Format
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Historic'); //Use this line if you want to get the folder by name
  //--> var folder = DocsList.getFileById('YYYYY'); //Use this line if you want to get the folder by ID
  var backup = DocsList.getFileById(SSID).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID).getName() + "_" + CopyDate);
  backup.addToFolder(folder); //This line will be move the folder
  backup.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder()); //This line is needed to remove the Filde from the Root
  ```

Comment: Indeed, opening the Spreadsheets should occur only once in the method ShellCopyValues​​() and pass the selected sheets ('sheet1', 'sheet2', 'Sheet3' ...) as parameters to the method CopyRows(sourcesheet, targetsheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particularly used [addToFolder(parent)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#addToFolder%28Folder%29), [removeFromFolder(parent)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#removeFromFolder%28Folder%29) and [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#getParents%28%29).

Try:

```
   ...
   var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Historic');
   var backup = DocsList.getFileById(SSID).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID).getName() + "_" + CopyDate);
   var deleteFromFolder = backup.getParents()[0];
   backup.addToFolder(folder);
   backup.removeFromFolder(deleteFromFolder);
   ...
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any example script to do this?

Comment: William the ShellCopyValues​​() + CopyRows open the sheet one time but the script Copyrows run for every sheet, that way the script create 4 copy of the same sheet.. 1 once the Sheet1 is updated, other once the sheet 2 is updated, other to sheet 3 and sheet 4

Comment: I understand that the procedure should be open both spreadsheets, iterate over the sheets to copy and create the backup.

In your code for each iteration to copy the sheets, open both spreadsheets and generate a backup, you may need to change a little bit the part.

Comment: I fixed the issue, please see the edit once again. I move the code at the end of script SheelCopyValue().-

Comment: William, I found an issue the script is not moved the Spreadsheet to folder Historic, is sharing from root callid "My Driver" into the historic.

Comment: Really "move" is to addToFolder() and removeFromFolder(), I do not see removeFromFolder() in your code.

Comment: William, addtoFolder is not move, just add the file like as shortcut into the folder "historic" but the file is not really in the folder still in My Driver (root). If I use removefromfolder to the file on My Driver also will delete from My Driver and the "file" (shortcut) in the folder "historic". I think addToFolder just add priviligies to that file to appear into a specif folder like logic file but the fisical file still into the root

Comment: I left a gist demonstration code that copies a file and then "move" it to a particular folder. I hope you find it useful. https://gist.github.com/wchiquito/5932870

Comment: Yes, it runs on Apps Script. Create a new spreadsheet and opens the code editor where you can run it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32965/discussion-between-william-chiquito-and-lad-service-desk)

Comment: William, I fixed the issue adding (1)backup.addToFolder(folder); //This line will be move the folder

(2)backup.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder()); //This line is needed to remove the Filde from the Root

Comment: Good for the solution! Theoretically backup.getParents()[0] should be equal to DocsList.getRootFolder() in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DriveApp` ... get the file using `getFileById(id)` then use `makeCopy(name)`

then

Use `DocsList` ... get the file using `getFileById(id)` then use `addToFolder(folder)`

I don't think there is an `addtofolder` in `DriveApp` and the file objects in `DocsList` and `DriveApp` are not the same

Comment: Please could you see my edit? thanks... Also I don't know how can I tell to the script where (folder) I want to save that copy. The script is create the copy in the root but I want to save in a specific path

Comment: Only one issue now... when the script run create 4 copy, I want to only create the copy once all sheet are updated

Comment: I fixed the issue, please see the edit once again. I move the code at the end of script SheelCopyValue()

Comment: Davif, I found an issue the script is not moving the Spreadsheet to folder Historic, is sharing from root callid "My Driver" into the historic.
<br>
That mean all copies are in the root "My Driver" and said shared in Historic Folder